# Can't create a .db file in assets folder

Tags: c++, sql, blackberry-10

I am trying to create a quizz.db file in assets folder by first creating a temporary `quizz.db` in data folder and then creating tables inside it and then copy it to the assets folder. By debugging the code it shows that the folder is created. But I can't find it in assets folder. Here is the code,

```
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <bb/data/SqlDataAccess>

using namespace bb::cascades;
using namespace bb::data;

SQLTest::SQLTest(bb::cascades::Application *app): QObject(app)
{
const QString fileName = QString("quizz.db");
QString dataFolder = QDir::homePath();
QString newFileName = dataFolder + "/" + fileName;
QTemporaryFile file(newFileName);

// Open the file that was created
if (file.open())
{
    // Create an SqlDataAccess object
    SqlDataAccess sda(newFileName);

    // Create a table called Employee in the database file
    sda.execute("CREATE TABLE Employee( firstName VARCHAR(50),lastName VARCHAR(50), salary INT);");

    // Insert employee records into the table
    sda.execute("INSERT INTO Employee (firstName, lastName, salary) VALUES (\"Mike\", \"Chepesky\", 42000);");
    sda.execute("INSERT INTO Employee (firstName, lastName, salary) VALUES (\"Westlee\", \"Barichak\", 55000);");
    sda.execute("INSERT INTO Employee (firstName, lastName, salary) VALUES (\"Ian\", \"Dundas\", 47000);");
    if(sda.hasError())
    {

    }
    else
        copyFileToAssetsFolder("quizz.db");
}
}

void SQLTest::copyFileToAssetsFolder(const QString fileName)
{
QString appFolder(QDir::homePath());
appFolder.chop(4);
QString originalFileName = appFolder + "app/native/assets/" + fileName;
QFile newFile(originalFileName);
// If I enable this `if` condition the code satisfies it and removes the quizz.db file and then it satisfies the next `if` condition and successfully copies the quizz.db file from `data` folder to `assets` folder.
/*if(newFile.exists())
    QDir().remove(originalFileName);*/
// this `if` condition is not satisfied. Which should mean the quizz.db file has been created on assets folder.
if (!newFile.exists())
{
    // If the file is not already in the assets folder, we copy it from the
    // data folder (read and write) to the assets folder (read only).
    QString dataFolder = QDir::homePath();
    QString newFileName = dataFolder + "/" + fileName;
    QFile originalFile(newFileName);

    if (originalFile.exists())
    {
        // Create sub folders if any creates the SQL folder for a file path like e.g. sql/quotesdb
        QFileInfo fileInfo(originalFileName);
        QDir().mkpath (fileInfo.dir().path());

        if(!originalFile.copy(originalFileName)) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to copy file to path: " << originalFileName;
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to copy file data base file does not exists.";
    }
}

// mSourceInDataFolder = newFileName;
}
```

If I enable the commented `if` condition of `copyFileToAssetsFolder` function it removes already created quizz.db file in assets folder (which Im unable to find) and goes inside the next `if` condition and copies the quizz.db created on the `data` folder to assets fodler. But in any case I can't find the quizz.db in assets folder. I really need help with this quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its not possible to modify assets folder mentioned in [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/accessible_folders.html) Now I am creating my db file in the data folder as it is writable.

Comment: The .BAR file normally contains a folder "assets", I would expect it to be linked from app home dir to the archive, and since you can't modify the .BAR (that would mean, you could change a signed application...) you will not be able to change assets dir or its content. Well, you found your solution by yourself, I just wanted to explain the possible cause for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Files in asset can not be modified